# Determine if place is opened by the time close and open

Tags: java, android-studio

Let's say I have a place open at 8 and close at 23 and the time is 22

I want to determine if the place is close at my current time with if statement or any.(By places I mean like restaurants etc.) I tried `22 <= 23 && 22 >= 8` but I think its wrong.

The time format is `hh.mm`. It will be a `double` value. For example:

```
Time = 23.59 means 23 hour 59 minutes
```

Can anyone help me with this exercise?

Comment: Is my math wrong or it seems correct to me. Why do you think its wrong?

Comment: Lack of confidence i think sorry

Comment: I think it's wrong when it's compared to other places I tried or something please check it and tell me if it gonna work on all places no matter what if they meet the same technique?

Comment: Will the time only be specified by `hh` or `hh:mm` is also possible? What do mean by places?

Comment: Yes but as double let's say like 23.59 or something (23 is hour 59 is minute)

Comment: I mean by places like restaurants etc..

Comment: It seems correct. Did you face any problems when using this expression? If so, then what was that?

Comment: I think I tried another place and it gives the wrong answer please allow me minutes to get that specific times of the try <3

Comment: The corner cases might be there. For example, your place opens at 8 and closes at 00. In this case it will result in wrong answer if you compare it straightaway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232122/discussion-between-aksingh-and-meismenomatterwhat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach which you are using:

```
1: if opening time < current time < closing time
2:     return true
3: else
4:     return false
```

Your approach is correct for general test cases. However, *it does not handle corner cases*.

---

### Corner Cases

**Case 1**:

```
Inputs:
Opening time: 22.00    Closing time: 4.00    Current time: 23.00

Expected Output:
true

Output:
false
```

**Case 2**:

```
Inputs:
Opening time: 22.00    Closing time: 4.00    Current time: 2.00

Expected Output:
true

Output:
false
```

---

### Algorithm

```
1: if opening time > closing time and current time < closing time
2:     current time += 24
3: if opening time > closing time
4:     closing time += 24
5: if opening time < current time < closing time
6:     return true
7: else
8:     return false
```

---

I test this algorithm against few sample test cases. It has worked for all of them. If you find any problems, do comment and I will try to resolve them.